# What is the Object in which public group data is stored?

Tags: object, public-group

I want to find a way to create public group in salesforce using data loader. For that i need the object in which public groups are stored.
Can anyone tell me the object in which public groups are stored?

Answer (score 4):

Public Group API Name is [`Group`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_group.htm) and to add members use [`GroupMember`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm).

In Dataloader, if Group does not display in the default list, check **Show all objects** to see a complete list of objects that you can access.

Comment: I tried that..but the problem is there are around 500 objects in my org..and i don't know which object stores the public groups..i checked all the related objects like group,public group etc..but they are not storing public groups

Comment: Maybe edit your question and add more details. Chances of getting better support would increase.